# C Programming How to convert macro to function

Tags: c, function, macros

I need to know how to convert any #define for .c (source) and .h (header) files.

```
#define ELAPSED_TIME(currentTime, startTime) (currentTime - startTime)
```

Comment: What do you mean by convert? If you mean replace then that can be done in pre-compile step e.g. gcc -E my_source.c

Comment: Add suitable types, braces, `return`, and a semicolon. (That particular macro is broken, by the way. `ELAPSED_TIME(3, 1+1);` should be 1, but is 3.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for example:

```
int elapsed_Time (int currentTime, int startTime)
{
    return (currentTime - startTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessed macros are simply text replacement , so if you convert such macro in function then you must bind it with some type , here looking at macro definition I am not sure generic (void*) type will work here. In c++ you can templatise the same, but this is simply replacement so if you have genric usage like for float/char/int/uint/long so better to keep it or templatize it in c++ or use (void*) in c function and do the subtraction on lowest unit level (eg char by char ).